# Text to Speech using C# Speak in Custom Voice

Tags: c#, text-to-speech

I want to play a text as audio eg text to speak in window application. But i want it in custom voice like Jigsaw voice. Im using c# .net framework 4.5 , visual studio 2015.How can i achieve it ? 
here is my code, there is only one button for speak

```
 if(richTextBox1.Text!="")
        {
            speechSynthesizerObj = new SpeechSynthesizer();
            //Asynchronously speaks the contents present in RichTextBox1
            speechSynthesizerObj.SelectVoiceByHints(VoiceGender.Male,VoiceAge.Senior);


            speechSynthesizerObj.SpeakAsync(richTextBox1.Text);

            btn_Pause.Enabled = true;
            btn_Stop.Enabled = true;

        }
```